# Representing the x-component of a circular arc.

Tags: trigonometry

This question stemmed from my attempts to brush up on the physics of electricity and magnetism after being away from school a long while (specifically a problem related to a uniform charge across a circular arc). I suspect the flaw exists in my mathematical reasoning, however, and for now have left those particulars out. Here is what I (incorrectly) reasoned:

•   $\cos(θ)$ = adjacent/hypotenuse.

•   On the unit circle, the hypotenuse is always $1$.

•   Over $0 ≤ θ ≤ \frac{π}{2}$, $\cos(θ)$ can be interpreted as the $x$-component as it is traced counterclockwise from the $x$-axis to the $y$-axis.

•   This unit-circle $x$-component could also be represented using a modified version of circle equation $r^2 = x^2 + y^2$ (i.e., $x = \sqrt{1-y^2}$ over the interval $0 ≤ y ≤ 1$).

•   The integrals intended to evaluate a sum of these x-components, however, yield different results. The bounds of integration are different, but are they not different interpretations of the same model?

Where is my flaw in reasoning? I know it will be something obvious, but I've been struggling with this since early this morning. Thanks!

Comment: What are the integrals you are trying to evaluate?

Comment: I apologize for the ambiguity. Both times I am attempting to sum all of the x-component contributions of force on a test charge (at the origin) from a circular arc, but I didn't want to bog the question down with the physics elements (I wasn't sure this was even appropriate for a math forum). I hope I have edited the question sufficiently.

Comment: I think you should put all the elements of your problem. It may be that you are doing a discrete sum and trying to approximate with an integral. It may also be that there is a function associated with the $x$ coordinate, and when you change from polar to orthogonal coordinates, you have to change the function  as well accordingly.

Comment: On the left is the correct answer. On the right is my answer.$2*\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{3}} R*cos\Theta d\Theta \neq 

2*\int_{0}^{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}} R*\sqrt{1-y^{2}}dy$ I'm working on posting the book question now.

Comment: "Imagine a plastic rod having a uniformly distributed charge -Q. The rod has been bent with a 120 degree circular arc of radius r. We place coordinate axes such that the axis of symmetry of the rod lies along the x axis and the origin is at the center of curvature P of the rod. In terms of Q and r, what is the electric field E due to the rod at point P." The book says just swap a ds = r cos dtheta and your done. Little explanation and no mathematical proof. That answer drove me bonkers. I was trying to reconcile this using a rectangular expression (without success).

Comment: Note that I've stripped away all of the point-charge constants, as they will be the same for both sides.

Comment: The issue is that you changed $ds$ with $dx$, basically. However, $ds$ is a function of both $dx$ and $dy$, since it is a an infinitesimal path on the rod. Even if this is infinitesimal, you have to take into account that all "as small as possible" things are not equal... In your case, you see that $ds$ close to the $x$ axis is mostly a $dy$, but when you "climb up", the portion of $dx$ increase as a part of the $ds$

Comment: I think you have given me a direction, but I need to look that this with fresh eyes in the morning. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

$$\newcommand{\d}[1]{{\rm d}#1}
\newcommand{\f}{\frac}
\newcommand{\K}[0]{\frac1{\rm 4\pi\varepsilon_0}}
\newcommand{\b}[1]{\left(#1\right)}
\d q=\f{Q}{\phi R}R\d \theta\\
\d E=\K\f{\d q}{R^2}\\
E=\int\d E\cos\theta=\K\f{ Q}{\phi R^2}\int_{-\phi/2}^{\phi/2}\cos\theta\d \theta\\\fbox{$\displaystyle E=\K\f{2Q\sin\b{\phi/2}}{\phi R^2}$}$$

Comment: Essentially I am asking the the topic after that one. I'm looking for a circular arc of radius R from -60 degrees to +60 degrees. The y component is symmetric, and I am asked to determine the x component. This book simply says plug in dq = lamda * ds = lamda * r * dtheta. Also to toss in a cos theta for good measure, but no mathematical proof or explanation. I was attempting to reconcile what was going on using rectantular coordinates but have failed every time. Forgive the lack of formatting...I am learning latex as we speak.

Comment: @Hiatt_J edited